# Some items in ListView can't be clicked

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using a ListView inside LinearLayout with custom row layout (2 TextViews). The ListView is populed with strings from a raw file. I'm also using `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"`on ListView. I've also implemented onClickListener. Testing the app on an emulator, it works fine, all items can be clicked and activity for that item starts. But when testing on an actual device, only about a 100 of over 10000 items can be clicked. When clicking on others, nothing happens.
Is there anything wrong with the following code?

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.definitions);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    try 
    {
        HashMap<String, String> item;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, ";");
            if (strings.length <= 2) 
            {
                item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                item.put("line1", strings[0].trim());
                item.put("line2", strings[1].trim());
                list.add(item);
            }
        }


        mTextView.setText("");

        sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
                R.layout.result,
                new String[] { "line1","line2" },
                new int[] {R.id.word, R.id.definition});

        mListView.setAdapter(sa);

        reader.close();

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GesloActivity.class);
                Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(PodajalecGesel.CONTENT_URI,
                                                String.valueOf(id+1));
                wordIntent.setData(data);
                startActivity(wordIntent);
            }
        });
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Doing some testing, I think the problem is in the database, which reades strings from raw file (similar to the code below), because it doesn't read all the line from txt file, only about a 100. Again, this is only on an actual device, it works fine in emulator.